# s3 beginner - how to use new s3 structure?

Tags: r

Below I've created a function which returns a structure returns with a new object with modified attributes

```
f <- function(loc) {
  structure(list(loc = loc , arg1=0 , c_val=c()),
            class="myclass")
}
```

My understanding of this code is : attaches 3 attributes to the object list. 
The attributes are loc , `arg1` and `c_val()` . A new class named `myclass` is associated with this function.

Using a new function how to add values to this structure and maintain state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loc`, `arg1` and `val` are components of the internal list structure, sometimes referred to as slots.  Attributes would be something different.

With the constructor that you already created you get many methods for free although you could override them.

```
# create a new object
obj <- f(1)

# get arg1
obj$arg1
## [1] 0

# update arg1
obj$arg1 <- 2

# get arg1
obj$arg1
## [1] 2

print(obj)
```

The last one gives:

```
$loc
[1] 1

$arg1
[1] 2

$c_val
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "myclass"
```

Define a custom print method:

```
print.myclass <- str
print(obj)
```

which gives:

```
List of 3
 $ loc  : num 1
 $ arg1 : num 2
 $ c_val: NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "myclass"
```

Define a custom getter:

```
`$.myclass` <- function(x, name) {
   cat("getting", name, "\n")
   .subset2(x, name)
}
obj$arg1
```

giving:

```
getting arg1 
[1] 2
```

If you need examples see the zoo package which defines S3 classes, `zoo`, `zooreg`, `yearmon` and `yearqtr` and many methods for each.

Answer (score 1):

A summary answer to your question is that you'll need to create getter and setter functions as part of your object definition, and give them names when you generate the object with `list()`.

```
myObject <- function(x){
     # create attributes
     attribute1 <- NULL
     attribute2 <- NULL
     # create getter and setter functions, using <<- form of assignment operator
     setAttribute1 <- function(x) attribute1 <<- x
     getAttribute1 <- function() attribute1
     setAttribute2 <- function(x) attribute2 <<- x
     getAttribute2 <- function() attribute2
     list(setAttribute1 = setAttribute1,
          getAttribute1 = getAttribute1,
          setAttribute2 = setAttribute2,
          getAttribute2 = getAttribute2)
}
```

Naming the functions in the `list()` function is a key step, because it allows you to access the functions via the `$` form of the Extract Operator.

Having defined our object, let's use it to set and get values for `attribute1`.

```
x <- myObject()

x$setAttribute1(15)
x$getAttribute1()
```

This code generates the following output to the R console.

```
> x <- myObject()
> 
> x$setAttribute1(15)
> x$getAttribute1()
[1] 15
>
```

For more detail on this topic including background on the use of the `<<-` form of the assignment operator, I'll refer you to an article I wrote for the Johns Hopkins University *R Programming* course on Coursera that addresses this specific problem, [Demystifying makeVector()](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-breakingDownMakeVector.md).